# Apple add icon to home screen open in Safari only

Tags: ios, safari, apple-touch-icon

I have created numerous resolutions of `apple-touch-icon`for my website. This means when someone adds my website to their Apple device Home Screen it has that icon. However when you click the icon it opens in a standalone window, rather than in the Safari browser.

I have tried using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">`but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way of preventing this from happening and make the webpage open in Safari only?

Comment: i think your looking for user agent

Comment: @COOOL What is that and how do I use it?

Comment: well you use user agent to determine the users browser -- but in your case it sounds like you trying to do something like this; which seems impractical -- > http://superuser.com/questions/384637/specific-browser-for-specific-links

Comment: @YourConscious I'm not sure you completely understand what is happening. When a user adds my website to their iPhone/iPad home screen by pressing the "share" button then "Add to Home Screen" it opens as a standalone window/tab, rather than in Safari their browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a way. Remove these lines from `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

And remove `minimal-ui` from:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

(if defined)

Here is the source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5967053?tstart=0

If your app doesn't have that `<meta>` tags it should open directly inside Safari (at least mine does).

Comment: I will give this a go when I get a chance. Thanks

Comment: It turns out that my website included `apple-mobile-web-app-capable YES` in the head by default, so it was my fault. Thanks for the thread link though.